# Watch command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, watch

I'd like to do `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` in a Jupyter notebook, but it only shows a single line. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I was able to do, to keep printing the GPU info.

```
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
  !nvidia-smi
  clear_output(wait=True)
```